# 'whatever' has no declared type

Tags: compiler-construction, parsing, bison

i am developing parser using bison...in my grammar i am getting this error

Here is a code

```
extern NodePtr  CreateNode(NodeType, ...);
extern NodePtr  ReplaceNode(NodeType, NodePtr); 
extern NodePtr  MergeSubTrees(NodeType, ...); 


            ...................


NodePtr   rootNodePtr = NULL; /* pointer to the root of the parse tree */
NodePtr   nodePtr = NULL; /* pointer to an error node */


                         ...........................

NodePtr   mainMethodDecNodePtr = NULL;

                   ................

/* YYSTYPE */

%union {
 NodePtr nodePtr;
}
```

i am getting this error whenever i use like $$.nodePtr or $1.nodePtr ... I am getting Parser.y:1302.32-33: $1 of `Expressi
on' has no declared type

Comment: Post more of Parser.y around line 1302 (at least 10 lines or so), to make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means that the first item (terminal or non-terminal) on the RHS of the `Expression` rule on line 1302 of parser.y has no type declared for it.  If its a terminal, you need to add `%token` declarations for it, and if its a non-terminal, you need to add a `%type` declaration for it.  When you do that (probably either `$type <nodePtr>` or `%token <nodePtr>`), you will access the value as just `$1` (no `.nodePtr` suffix)

*edit*

sounds like line 1302 should be `$$ = $1;`.  The `%type <nodePtr> XXX` should go in the first section, where XXX is the non-terminal for this rule.  When you use `%union` in a .y file, the tags declared in the union should ONLY be used in `%type` and `%token` declarations -- they should not appear in any action in the .y file

Comment: line at 1302 is $$.nodePtr = $1.nodePtr;....
 in %union {
 NodePtr nodePtr;
} NodePtr is structure...

Comment: you mean if nodePtr is of type Structure NodePtr then it should be %type <nodePtr> NodePtr ?

Comment: No, `%type` is used to declare which member of the `%union` is associated with a given non-terminal in the grammar.  Since you haven't posted any of your grammar, I don't know what that would be.